# Jquery $.each parallelism

Tags: jquery, parallel-processing

I have a bit of jQuery code which finds a bunch of  tags on the page then reads a specific attribute of theirs and base on that it updates their style.

I am wondering if $.each function runs through the collection in a multi-threaded manner? If not, how can I make it process several items of the collection concurrently?

```
function setPreviewImages() {
        var anchorElement = $('.ajaxImageHolder');

        anchorElement.each(function () {
            var imgUrl = $( this ).attr("data-imageUrl");
            $( this ).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
        });
};
```

Comment: No it isn't. JavaScript is single-threaded. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Thanks. We have a web page which displays quite a few of photos on the page. The page takes almost 7 seconds to load, which is too slow for a mobile site. I did some diagnostics and turned out that loading the images was a big part of the problem.  With the code given above I let the page load, then I assign the image urls to their relative tags. This way users can use the site while the images are being loaded. I want to speed this up by parallelism. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, one option is [_lazy-loading_](https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil/).